# resizing and storing image folder with filesystem using python

Tags: python, postgresql

I want to resize images in the folder and store them into database with filesystem using postgres as database and jupyter notebook. I am using resize function for resizing my images and then saving then into database but resize function seems not working and unable to understand my mistake.

```
subject= input("Enter Subject Name:")
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s"%(subject))
cursor.execute( """CREATE TABLE %s (ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, PHOTO BYTEA NOT NULL)"""%(subject))
conn.commit()

userfilepath=input("enter file path:")
dirs = os.listdir( userfilepath )


def resize():
    for item in dirs:
        if os.path.isfile(userfilepath+item):
            im = Image.open(userfilepath+item)
            f, e = os.userfilepath.splitext(userfilepath+item)
            imResize = im.resize((200,200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            imResize.save(f + ' resized.jpg', 'JPEG', quality=90)



import cv2 
import os, sys
from PIL import Image
import io
import glob 
img_dir = userfilepath  # Enter Directory of all images  
data_path = os.path.join(img_dir,'*g') 
files = glob.glob(data_path) 
data = [] 
for f1 in files: 
    # img = cv2.imread(f1) 
    # data.append(img) 

     with open(f1,"rb") as file:
             resize()
             BinaryData=file.read()
             cursor.execute("INSERT INTO {tab} (photo)  
             VALUES({})".format(psycopg2.Binary(BinaryData, ) , tab=subject  ) )
             conn.commit()
             #Insert_blob(img_dir)
```

Comment: It would be helpful to put any occuring errors in the question post!...
Does `os.path.isfile(userfilepath+item)` return a sensible path, with appropriate slashes? why not use something like `os.path.join()` to be sure

Comment: actually i was not getting any error but also not getting resized images.

Comment: By using os.path.join(userfilepath+item)  I'm getting an error that is FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\my_profile\\Desktop\\unresized1.jpg'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel free to change the variables at the top since you seem to want to get them from user input. I've chosen to hardcode them for the purpose of this example.

Have a look at the code below

```
import os

userfilepath = "files"
dirs = os.listdir("files")


def do_open(_file):
    print(f"Opening {_file}")


def do_resize(_file):
    print(f"resizing: {_file}")


def resize():
    for item in dirs:
        f = userfilepath + item
        print(f)
        if os.path.isfile(f):
            im = do_open(userfilepath + item)
            

resize()
# output 
# filesf1.txt
# filesf2.txt


def resize_well():
    for item in dirs:
        f = os.path.join(userfilepath, item)
        print(f)
        if os.path.isfile(f):
            im = do_open(f)



resize_well()
# output
# files\f1.txt
# Opening files\f1.txt
# files\f2.txt
# Opening files\f2.txt
```

In `resize_well()` `os.path.join()` creates a proper path, where as using string concatenation misses out the `/` or `\` delimiter on linux and windows respectively.

Your code isn't passing the `if` statement because `userfilepath+item` doesn't exist, but probably `userfilepath/item` does.

Comment: No problem! Happy coding! )